# JavaFX8 tabpane's tab not switching

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Below is my code for GridPane with TabPane.

There are 2 tabs inside a TabPane.

When I click preview on SceneBuilder the tabs are not switching upon clicking on the tab head.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
    <GridPane id="content" alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="310.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="mainParent" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.gvj.sndp.view.controller.HomeController">
      <children>
          <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.18421052631578946" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
            <items>
                <TreeView fx:id="menuTreeView" prefHeight="273.0" prefWidth="115.0" />
                <TabPane fx:id="tabPane" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" rotateGraphic="true">
                   <tabs>
                      <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                      <Tab text="Untitled Tab">
                        <content>
                          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                        </content>
                      </Tab>
                   </tabs></TabPane>
            </items>
          </SplitPane>
      </children>
      <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="-1.0" prefWidth="-1.0" />
      </columnConstraints>
      <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="22.0" prefHeight="30.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        <RowConstraints maxHeight="35.0" minHeight="22.0" prefHeight="22.0" valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
          <RowConstraints valignment="CENTER" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
      </rowConstraints>
    </GridPane>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expected that it doesn't do anything on mouse click as you set it transparent for mouse events: `mouseTransparent="true"`

```
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane" mouseTransparent="true" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" rotateGraphic="true">
```

I guess it was done by accident, but when you set [mouseTransparent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#mouseTransparentProperty) property to true:

> If true, this node (together with all its children) is completely
>   transparent to mouse events. When choosing target for mouse event,
>   nodes with mouseTransparent set to true and their subtrees won't be
>   taken into account.

Remove the mentioned part from your FXML and your preview will work like a charm.

**In SceneBuilder, on the Properties Tab of TabPane:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TreeView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TabPane nodeOrientation="LEFT_TO_RIGHT" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="Tab1" />
          <Tab text="Tab2">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="229.0" prefWidth="600.0" />
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Change here tabpane according to your required size.